# I'm looking for a way to extract job numbers out of text using regular expressions with python

Tags: python, regex

If the text is 'Job 45, job 32 and then job 15' I'd like to get a result of
['job 45', 'job 32', 'job 15'] or ['45', '32', '15']

I tried r'[job]\d+' which returns an empty list.

```
re.findall(r'[job]\d+', 'Job 45, job 32 and then job 15'.lower())
[]
```

I experimented with splitting on job.

```
re.split(r'job','Job 45, job 32 and then job 15'.lower())
['', ' 45, ', ' 32 and then ', ' 15']
```

I tried splitting on words.

```
re.findall(r'\w+','Job 45, job 32 and then job 15'.lower())
['job', '45', 'job', '32', 'and', 'then', 'job', '15']
```

which is workable .. I can check if an element is 'job' and if the following element can be converted to a number.

What would be a regular expression to get either ['job 45', 'job 32', 'job 15'] or ['45', '32', '15'] from  'Job 45, job 32 and then job 15' ?

Comment: `[job]` is a regex that matches a single character, that is any one of `j`, `o`, or `b`.  The regex that matches `job` is `job`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex `[job]\d+` has couple of problems,

`[job]` is a character set which means it will match only one character either j or o or b

Second problem, there is no provision of space between job and number in your regex.

Third problem, as your input text contains Job as well as job, so to make a case insensitive match, you need (?i) flag.

So your corrected form of regex becomes this,

```
(?i)job\s+\d+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uBICc5/1)

Sample python code

```
import re
s = 'Job 45, job 32 and then job 15';
str = re.findall('(?i)job\s+\d+', s)
print(str)
```

This gives following output,

```
['Job 45', 'job 32', 'job 15']
```

Comment: Not a likely thing to happen, but you may want to put a word boundary `\b` on the left side of `job`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: You are right though but unless OP's text had something like 'job 24, hotjob 52, job 25' where he didn't intend to match 'hotjob' that extra \b only makes the regex a little large by 2 more characters :) And who knows may be he intended to match 'hotjob 52 too' :)

Answer (score 1):

Or much easier using `'job (\d+)'` expression:

```
>>> re.findall('job (\d+)',s.lower())
['45', '32', '15']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use the following pattern, which uses a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=\bjob )\d+
```

This captures any group of digits which are immediately preceded by the text `job` (case insensitive) followed by a single space.

```
text = "Job 45, job 32 and then job 15"
res = re.findall(r'(?<=\bjob )\d+', text, re.I)
print(res)

['45', '32', '15']
```

Comment: I love the anonymous downvote of a completely valid answer.

Comment: I find it strange too. I used your example in the code I wrote.